# Elegant solution to read and transform query string in php?

Tags: php, query-string

I have a query string such as this:

```
file.php?search=keyword+here&genre1=1&genre4=1&genre19=1&genre181&director=436&actor=347&search_rating=3
```

I need to extract all the genres mentioned in the string, in this case its

```
genre1, genre4, genre19 and genre18
```

and output them into a string such as

```
ge1_ge4_ge19_ge18
```

What would be a good solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the parameters passed by query string to the currently executing script then you simply need:

```
$genres = preg_grep('!^genre!', array_keys($_GET));
$out = implode('_', $genres);
```

Here you're filtering out all the parameters that start with `genre` using [`preg_grep()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) and getting a list of parameter names using [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php).

If you have a URL you need to parse then use this snippet:

```
$url = 'file.php?search=keyword+here&genre1=1&genre4=1&genre19=1&genre181&director=436&actor=347&search_rating=3';
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $params);
$genres = preg_grep('!^genre!', array_keys($params));
echo implode('_', $genres);
```

The difference here is that you use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to extract the query string and [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to parse the query string.

Output:

```
genre1_genre4_genre19_genre181
```

Comment: How CPU intensive is this? preg is a little slow, no?

Comment: If not used thousands of times in a loop, totally, totally harmless.

Comment: +1 for nice, ready-to-run solution. Just the transformation to `ge_xxx` is missing but the OP has not defined that yet.

Comment: @Yegor: `preg_grep()` is a convenience. You can do it without using a loop and checking what the array key starts with but unless you're doing this tens of thousands of times in a single script execution it's not even worth worrying about.

Answer (score 2):

**[parse_str()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)**  with the optional `$arr` argument is specifically built for exploding a query string properly:

> Parses str  as if it were the query string passed via a URL and sets variables in the current scope.

It can even deal with array arguments.

[**http_build_query()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) can glue an array back together with a custom `$arg_separator` but to get the output specifically as you want it, you will have to manually iterate through the arguments to make the transformation.

Answer (score 0):

You could explode on the '=' then join on '_'.